# How to add "+" button on full calendar on day cell

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar modification with resource view:

http://www.ikelin.com/jquery-fullcalendar-resource-day-view/

I want to add `+` button where the events are like this:
[image]

If there's event on the day cell show that add button.

I tried to do this on `viewDisplay`

```
viewDisplay: function (view) {
                    $(".fc-day-number").prepend("(+) ");
                        },
```

But the add button is not shown. what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

viewDisplay event does not exists anymore.
you can use viewRender insted.

see documentation:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/removed/viewDisplay/